# Autofit a row with respect to a cell but not all the rows of the cells

Tags: excel, row, height, listobject

I have a table in Excel (listobject) which loads texts in the cells depending on certain criteria.

Once loaded I would like to "autofit" the cells of a column (all cells of the listobjects have property wraptext=true) But I do not want autofit of the cells of column 5 (because they contain many lines each.

This is the code I have so far

```
dim SRTbl as listobject
set SRTbl = thisworkbook.sheets(1).listobjects(1)

' all rows height 14
SRTbl.DataBodyRange.RowHeight = 14

'I would like that the cells of column 4 are autofit-ed
'but NOT the cells of column 5
SRTbl.listcolumns(4).databodyrange.entirerow.autofit
```

This does not work because it autofits the whole row. In Column 5 the cells contain a multy-line text and I only want the autofit for the content of the cells of column 4

The following does not work neither:

```
SRTbl.ListColumns(4).Cells.autofit
```

Just in case it is not entirely clear.
Column 4 contains text having 1, 2 or 3 lines.
Column 5 contains text having many lines >10

I want to adjust the height of the cells to the lines of the cells of column4 but not column 5.

thanks

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly I think you just need to change '.EntireRow' to '.EntireColumn'. If you can confirm that is what you actually need I'll add it as an answer

Comment: I just changed it in my code like this: SRTbl.ListColumns(1).EntireColumn.autofit     and it does not work   :-(

Comment: Looks like you've missed the DataBodyRange part. Try SRTbl.ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a break point on the line:
`SRTbl.listcolumns(4).databodyrange.entirerow.autofit`
.  In the Immediate pane of the IDE enter:
`SRTbl.listcolumns(4).databodyrange.entirerow.select` and you will see the whole row selected.

Change `SRTbl.listcolumns(4).databodyrange.entirerow.autofit` to `SRTbl.listcolumns(4).autofit` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. unfortunately autofit is not a method of listcolumns (the methods being only add, application, count, creator, item, Parent). hence the error given is "the object does not support this method). As for the first part of your answer it works, but does not solve the problem, since ALL the cells of the row get autofit-ed

Answer (score 0):

If we have a look at what your initial code was doing it was attempting to autofit every cell in the EntireRow of the column you selected. You just need to change the reference from .EntireRow to .EntireColumn.

The confusing thing here appears to be in the syntax as you might expect to be able to call Autofit directly from the table or range objects. Autofit is a function of the .EntireColumn object which in turn is a subset of either the .Range or .DataBodyRange objects.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim SRTbl As ListObject
    Set SRTbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)

    'I would like that the cells of column 4 are autofit-ed
    SRTbl.ListColumns(4).Range.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```